# Debugging swig template engine, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

Is there any way to debug swig template engine for node.js, because I don't get the exact file in which the error occurred in some cases,
 e.g.

```
{% set temp = JSON.parse('some random string') %}
```

This what I get in console for above:

```
2015-08-13T09:38:12.254Z - error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.eval [as tpl] (eval at <anonymous> (/home/saurabh/intl/via_node/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:498:13), <anonymous>:6:810)
at compiled (/home/saurabh/intl/via_node/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:619:18)
at Object.eval [as tpl] (eval at <anonymous> (/home/saurabh/intl/via_node/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:498:13), <anonymous>:27:611)
at compiled (/home/saurabh/intl/via_node/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:619:18)
at /home/saurabh/intl/via_node/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:559:20
at /home/saurabh/intl/via_node/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:690:9
at fs.js:268:14
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

There is no mention of the template file in which error occurred.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not a Swig/template issue but an issue with feeding incorrect data to `JSON.parse()`. I don't think that Swig can catch those in a way that would make it show where exactly it happened (without wrapping every generated line in a `try/catch` block).

Comment: I could not find any provision for try catch available in a swig template file.

Comment: There isn't. I think that parsing JSON in a template is a bit of an anti-pattern tbh, hence the lack of any features in Swig to mitigate any issues that occur during the parsing. You could create a custom filter or tag to catch errors, but that sounds like more of an ordeal than moving the JSON parsing to your JS code.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: You are right, the problem is 'some random string', you can't `JSON.parse` a string isn't a JSON.

So you should have something like this:

```
{% set temp = JSON.parse('{"test": true}') %}
```

Comment: I used it and I use it. `set temp` is wrong it's not Javascript and with the syntax `{% %}` you are doing javascript in the template. Probably you need to read something more.

Comment: Are you sure    var works for you, because I tried it and it gives syntax error in my case.

Comment: I gave that string just to produce the error, the problem is there is no way in swig template engine to detect in which line of file the error occured.